# PoweLevel9k Broke after brew upgrade

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

Error messages while executing commands in iterm.

```
build_left_prompt:8: failed to load module `zsh/regex': /usr/lib/zsh/5.4.1/zsh/regex.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
build_left_prompt:8: -regex-match not available for regex
build_right_prompt:8: failed to load module `zsh/regex': /usr/lib/zsh/5.4.1/zsh/regex.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
build_right_prompt:8: -regex-match not available for regex
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I figured it out myself, **just restarting the iterm worked**

looks like my `brew upgrade` changed my the zsh version and the folders got swapped and now the lib modules are in `/usr/lib/zsh/5.3/zsh/`
brew did symlink my new folders but the existing session remained broken.